# snowflake : filter the rows that contain the proper date value

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform

In Variant column : there are some rows contain the proper date value and some rows contain some string value .

I need to filter the rows that contain the proper date value .

Comment: Can you please provide some sample data and expected results?

Answer (score 0):

This should get you the info you need:

```
  with x as 
  ( 
      select parse_json('{"date":"2021-03-01"}') json union select parse_json('{"date":"No Date"}') 
  )
  select sum(case when try_to_date(x.json:date::string) is not null  then 1 else 0 end) valid_dates,
         sum(case when try_to_date(x.json:date::string) is null then 1 else 0 end) invalid_dates
  from   x;
```